# Fix my code to return a table of values

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

Here is a “procedural” program that we wrote in my class, implementing the
rectangle rule of numerical integration:

```
rect4[f_, a_, b_, n_] :=
( ex = Integrate[f[y], {y, a, b}] // N; 
res = {};
rat = {};
nErr = 0.0 ; 
Do[
   ( h = (b - a)/2.^nt; 
   tmp = h Sum[f[a + i h], {i, 0, 2^nt - 1}]; 
   oErr = nErr;
   nErr = Abs[ex - tmp]; 
   AppendTo[res, nErr ]; 
    If[nt > 1, AppendTo[rat, nErr/oErr]];
 ), {nt, 0, n}] 
)
```

This program currently has no means of displaying its output except by
explicitly requesting evaluation of *res* and *rat* after the program has executed. How do you remedy this deficiency by adapting the code to produce a three column table containing the values of `n`, the error for the corresponding value of `n` and the ratio of successive errors for `n = 2` through `n = 6`? Without using `Print`.

Comment: A call example to the function defined is needed

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
rect4[f_, a_, b_, n_] :=
 With[{ex = Integrate[f[y], {y, a, b}], r = Range[0, n]}, 
  With[{h = (b - a)/2.^r},
   {r, #, {"/"}~Join~Ratios@#}\[Transpose] &@
    Abs[ex - (b - a) Mean /@ f /@ Range[a, b - h, h]]]]

MatrixForm@rect4[#^2 &, -1, 1, 6]
```

[image]

Comment: how did you figure how to call it with no example given? very good. But I see no DO LOOP in your answer like the teacher code?  ;)

Comment: @Nasser Actually I just made a pact with the devil and got the ability to figure out the use of the code, at the cost of being unable to use `Do` in my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Just add an output line:

```
rect4[f_, a_, b_, n_] := (ex = Integrate[f[y], {y, a, b}] // N;
  res = {};
  rat = {};
  nErr = 0.0;
  Do[(h = (b - a)/2.^nt;
    tmp = h Sum[f[a + i h], {i, 0, 2^nt - 1}];
    oErr = nErr;
    nErr = Abs[ex - tmp];
    AppendTo[res, nErr];
    If[nt > 1, AppendTo[rat, nErr/oErr]];), {nt, 0, n}]; 
  Grid[Thread[{Range[0, n], res, {"", ""}~Join~rat}]])
```

e.g.

```
rect4[#^2 &, -1, 1, 10]
```

yields:

[image]